# Make Authenticated Requests work on Local Devserver

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I'm working on an endpoints API using Google's App Engine, using Java. All my API requests are authenticated, requiring a `User` object. However, when I start the devserver using `mvn appengine:devserver` and visit `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer`, I can see the methods, but switching on `OAuth 2.0` in the upper corner does nothing. I always get a `null` User object.

When I upload the add via `mvn appengine:update`, it works fine. Do I have to upload my test version every single time I'm testing my API methods? Doesn't that make development almost impossible once you go into production?

I could not find a single hint on how to make the OAuth working properly on the Dev Server, so is it possible at all?

**ADDENDUM**: I tried the login at `http://localhost:8080/_ah/login`, but trying to login there redirects to `http://localhost:8080/_ah/null`, a 404. And I still don't have a valid user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out (by accident, it was not documented anywhere) that when you activate the `remote_api` for the app, you can use the route `/_ah/login` properly, which then allows you to use OAuth on the devserver.

It worked on Python and Java when the Remote API is activated as described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi).

Just remove this when going to production, I guess. I don't know if it's an security issue.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth requires a callback URL from Google to your application.
Since the dev server is running locally, behind your router and firewall and everything, this will not work.

The only way to make it work that I'm aware of is to log in to the deployed application, and then manually copy the access token from the datastore to the dev store.

Alternatively, you could set the callback on the deployed application to log all the parameters, so you can replay the request locally.

Comment: Do you have anything on how to do that copying of the access token?

Comment: I'm using Python, but in my datastore there is a CredentialsModel. Just use the command line tools to copy them to the dev server. It's been a while since I used OAuth, so I can't tell you all the details.